# Problem running vmPlayer on Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, virtual-machine, vmware

After install the program and execute vmPlayer request the kernel headers to recompile it (I guess), after that vmP install the virtual network device, at this point show an error.

[image: this one]

and the vmware-15092.log file is:

```
  2015-03-27T22:51:28.154-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64".
2015-03-27T22:51:28.154-06:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64/build/include" for the kernel "3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-03-27T22:51:28.158-06:00| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2015-03-27T22:51:28.158-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64/build/include" for kernel release "3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64".
2015-03-27T22:51:28.158-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-03-27T22:51:28.158-06:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-03-27T22:51:28.158-06:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2015-03-27T22:51:28.164-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64".
2015-03-27T22:51:28.164-06:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64/build/include" for the kernel "3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-03-27T22:51:28.164-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2015-03-27T22:51:28.165-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2015-03-27T22:51:28.165-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64 to "/lib/modules/3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64/build/include".
2015-03-27T22:51:28.165-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64/build/include" for kernel release "3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64".
2015-03-27T22:51:28.165-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-03-27T22:51:28.165-06:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-03-27T22:51:28.165-06:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2015-03-27T22:51:28.171-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64".
2015-03-27T22:51:28.171-06:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64/build/include" for the kernel "3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-03-27T22:51:28.288-06:00| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64/build/Module.symvers
2015-03-27T22:51:28.288-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64/build/Module.symvers.
2015-03-27T22:51:28.302-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Read 15286 symbol versions
2015-03-27T22:51:28.302-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2015-03-27T22:51:28.304-06:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-03-27T22:51:28.381-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64/misc/vmnet.ko".
2015-03-27T22:51:28.381-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".


2015-03-27T22:51:28.385-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2015-03-27T22:51:28.385-06:00| vthread-4| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-3fL25O/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.19.1-201.fc21.x86_64/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2015-03-27T22:51:29.709-06:00| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Now I don't know what to do, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works on VM Player too.

[VMware Workstation 11 fails to build vmnet on Fedora 21](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/65849/vmware-workstation-11-fails-to-build-vmnet-on-fedora-21/)

Greetings!